# Java output to file in table format?

Tags: java, file-io, formatting

I have a bunch of info that I want to output to a file and it needs to be setup like a table. For example, I need columns with titles and information below each column.

I have four items being printed at a time that each need their own row. A %n before the next.

Should I use system.out.format? Should I be appending data to a file with the PrintStream class?

I would like to stick with Java's basic utilities and classes.

I want my output to look like this...

```
*Title1*  *Title2*  *Title3*  *Title4*  *Title5*
 info1     info1     info1     info1     info1
 info2     info2     info2     info2     info2
....3
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: look up formatting Strings using String.format(...).  The API for [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format) and for [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) will give you the details on how to use this.

Comment: @Hovercraft: that should be an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use code like this:

```
Formatter fmt = new Formatter(); 

System.out.println(fmt.format("%s %s %s %s %s", "Title*", "Title*", "Title*", "Title*", "Title*"));
```

See [Formatter java doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Sample code which prints table which has 20 characters column width:

```
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    System.out.println(formatter.format("%20s %20s %20s %20s %20s", "Title*", "Title*", "Title*", "Title*", "Title*"));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        formatter = new Formatter();
        String rowData = "info" + i;
        System.out.println(formatter.format("%20s %20s %20s %20s %20s", rowData, rowData, rowData, rowData, rowData));
    }
```

For writing data to file you can use [java.io](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) package